# How to pass null from C++ to Java via Qt JNI?

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I'm trying to pass a null value to a `QAndroidJniObject::callObjectMethod()` and I can't find how to do it.

The code:

```
void generateEncryptionKey()
{
    auto keyStore = getKeystore();
    auto generator = getKeyGenerator();

    keyStore.callObjectMethod(
                "load",
                "(Ljava/security/KeyStore/LoadStoreParameter;)V"
                // what to put here for null value?
                );
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `NULL`?

Comment: I'm not really skilled in C++ and when I checked what `NULL` macro expands to, it's just  `0` (zero), I wasn't sure if I could use that.

Comment: Well, if you look at [Oracle's JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) and read what functions like `NewObject` and `NewString` return if they fail, it's `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nullptr`: `NULL` doesn't belong in C++.

```
keyStore.callObjectMethod("load",
                          "(Ljava/security/KeyStore/LoadStoreParameter;)V", nullptr);
```